# Does Apple ever update the firmware on their USB C AC power adapters?

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, charging, power

I have a MacBook Air (Intel, 2020) that came with the 30W official Apple OEM power adapter.

If I use the power adapter with my MacBook Air and check “System Report > Hardware > Power” and scroll down to the bottom of the list, I see the following info; serial number obfuscated for public forum posting:

```
AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x1674
  Wattage (W):  30
  Family:   0xe000400a
  Serial Number:    FNT1234567890ABCD
  Name: 30W USB-C Power Adapter
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Firmware Version: 1020067
  Charging: No
```

I see that the “Firmware Version” has the value of 1020067. First, I am a bit stunned there is a firmware version for a power adapter like this. FWIW, looking up non-Apple power adapters show no firmware version at all.

So knowing that Apple OEM power adapters have a firmware version, does anyone have any insight into how official Apple OEM power adapters get firmware updates and if they even get updated at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be an indirect evidence that Apple may occasionally, or at least capable of, issuing updates for power adapters that come with Macs.

See this Apple support document, “About background updates in macOS”: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207005

In the document, there’s a mention that macOS system file updates may include

> - Firmware updates for Apple power adapters

Comment: This is not correct!  “Firmware updates for Apple power adapters” refers to the firmware contained on the Mac logic board as there is no firmware on the power adapter.

Comment: @Allan There is definitely firmware on these power adapters, and system report claims to report the version. Why do you think there isn't?

Comment: Yes.  The "firmware" you're referring to is the USB-PD and the circuitry to measure/control it.  The update in question is under "System Updates" not "Accessory Updates" meaning it updates the *Mac*.  You can also check and see that [no power adapter has ever received a firmware update](https://support.apple.com/downloads/power%2520adapter)

Comment: This is where misinformation  comes from (like resetting NVRAM/SMC and reinstalling macOS as some sort of solution to every problem)  and it's not an overreaction when someone disagrees with you.  In this case, you're taking a line out of context and applying it incorrectly.  Now, if your power adapter fails, you'll believe there *must* be a firmware image you can download to fix it when there won't be one.  But, to each their own...

Comment: So, why ask the question?  What good is updatable firmware if you won't address it in time of a failure?  I've updated BIOS/UEFI/firmware on many devices to solve issues, it's only prudent.  As for if/when Apple has updated firmware for power adapters, you would find them under "[Accessory Updates](https://support.apple.com/downloads/displaysandaccessories)"  The updates you referred to was for the Mac and is ostensibly for interfacing with newer chargers with new or updated standards.

Comment: No.  I applaud curiosity. My intention is to correct misinformation.  You asked a question and settled on “proof” that wasn’t. We are all entitled to opinions, but not our own facts.  Believe what you like, but I don't want others coming  away from here with false info.

Comment: I just got the Apple 35W USB-C Charger Adapter (the one with 2 USB-C stacked on top of each other).  When I plugged it in it showed firmware 1070070, I connected it with a USB-C to C cable to my MacBook Air M2 running Sonoma and within seconds it had updated to Firmware Version: 1070076

AC Charger Information:

  Connected: Yes
  ID: 0x701b
  Wattage (W): 34
  Family: 0xe000400a
  Serial Number: C4H222603ABCD1234
  Name: 35W USB-C Power Adapter 
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Hardware Version: 1.0
  Firmware Version: 1070076
  Charging: No